# endpoints Models google datastore NDB

Tags: google-app-engine, ndb

I have used this lib for ndb EndpointsModel in python2.7

```
from src.endpoints_proto_datastore.ndb import EndpointsModel
class Organization(EndpointsModel):
  Organization having account in the system '''
  company_name = ndb.StringProperty()
  address = ndb.TextProperty()
```

Now google app engine is no more support 2.7 python

Now how can i use this in python3.9 with django ?

Comment: Please check this documentation on [migrating to the Python 3 runtime](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/migration-center/standard/migrate-to-second-gen/python-differences). You may also check this documentation on [accessing legacy bundled services for Python 3](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/services/access) as this contains additional information on migration, compatibility, and example on accessing legacy bundled services for Python 3.